# How can I implement colour segmentation along with foreground detection in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

My problem is that, FG detection output is binary image (using MoG method). How could you restore this output into a 3-channel (RGB) image so that a colour segmentation algorithm like mean-shift can be used. My end goal is to detect the blob of 'largest coloured segment' in the FG by effectively omitting the BG.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `img` is your 3 channel image and `thresh` is your binary image. From what I understand, you want that the white part of thresh should retain its RGB value and the black part should remain black. You can do so as shown:

```
    Mat mask;
    cvtColor(thresh,thresh,CV_GRAY2BGR);//change thresh to a 3 channel image
    absdiff(img,img,mask);//initialize mask as a black image of img.size()
    subtract(thresh,img,mask);
    subtract(thresh,mask,mask);
```

Now `mask` will hold the filtered image with its RGB values.